# How to describe this type of a scholarship?

Tags: cv

Hi I'm applying to grad school and was writing my CV for the first time in my life, so had a question...

How do I describe a scholarship that was given upon entrance and lasts for four years and pays for 100% of the tuition? I've heard that a full scholarship refers to getting paid for 100% of tuition, but I couldn't find whether it refers to scholarships that last for four years or that last for one term.

I've written

"Samsung Science Scholarship (4 year full entrance scholarship)"

Would this be the correct way to put it? Or is it too formal? Is there a better way to put this?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I'm inclined to say just mention the scholarship name. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Scholarship - this seems to be known.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is though, that scholarship is different from my scholarship as far as I know (because mine is undergrad and that one is grad)

Comment: There’s quite a lot of scholarships with the name samsung attached to it so i thought i’d have to specify which one it is

Comment: Ah I agree, okay. Well, I would still write "Samsung Scholarship (4 yrs)" or so.

Comment: I see. So you dont recommend writing things like “full scholarship” and “entrance scholarship”? Or is it just unnecessary?

Comment: Thanks for the reply by the way!!

Comment: There are several instances of the phrase "full-tuition scholarship" by various organizations, including universities, if you search online. You can check if that will provide clarity in your context.

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing "entrance" in this context. The rest of what you wrote looks fine to me.